# JavaMail IMAP properties

Tags: email, properties, jakarta-mail, imap

I have been using the JavaMail API for quite sometime now and I have been implementing the POP3 protocol.
I am planning to implement the IMAP protocol now and wanted to know what are the necessary properties that I need to set for supporting IMAP.
I have currently set the following properties -

> Properties props = System.getProperties();
>   props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
>   props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", strConnectionTimeOut);

Are there any mandatory properties that need to be set in order to support IMAP?
Any help/advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No properties are mandatory.  What you need to set depends on the mail server you're using.

Comment: So, is it possible to connect to the POP3/IMAP server just by changing the parameter of `session.getStore()` ?

Comment: Mostly, yes.  But again, if you've set properties to configure the POP3 connection, you may need to set similar properties to configure the IMAP connection.